# Specify default arguments for Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

When I create playbooks I often add a comments section at the top on how to run the Ansible playbook. With more options becoming available in Ansible, the list of command-line arguments also seems to grow. It made me curious to see if there is a way to specify defaults for these arguments in the playbook.

For example my playbook needs the following arguments:

- the hosts file: `-i hosts`
- the password for become: `-K`
- the password for the vault: `--ask-vault-pass`
- the name of the playbook: `myplaybook.yml`

It would be easier if I could just run the following command (especially for co-workers):
`ansible-playbook myplaybook.yml`

And specify in the playbook, that by default it should look for a `hosts` inventory file and ask for sudo + vault passwords. Of course I could create a script and wrap the playbook command, but that adds another layer on top of it.

I guess I'm looking for adding something like this to my playbook:

```
vars:
  inventory_file: hosts
  ask_become_pass: true
  ask_vault_pass: true
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what the configuration file is for. Create an `ansible.cfg` in the directory from where you run `ansible`, like so:

```
[defaults]
inventory = hosts
ask_vault_pass = True

[privilege_escalation]
become_ask_pass = True
```

See also http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html

The `ansible.cfg` in the working directory precedes `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`. The full search order is described on the page linked above. Command line options you pass on invocation override all configuration files.

Comment: Thanks, that works great! Is there a way to specify `ask_vault_pass` in the playbook though? My folder contains multiple playbooks, some require the vault and others don't.

Comment: According to http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html, no. You can specify the `vault_password` as a secret, but I'm not sure that's an option for you. I haven't used vaults yet, so can't tell you more.